# Pattern matching for strings independent from symbols

Tags: regex, algorithm, language-agnostic, pattern-matching

I have need for an algorithm which can find pre-defined patterns in data (which is present in the form of strings) independent from the actual symbols/characters of the data and the pattern. I only care about the relations between the symbols, not the symbols themselves. It is also legal to have different pattern symbols for the same symbol in the data. The only thing the pattern matching algorithm has to enforce is that multiple occurences of the same symbol in the pattern are preserved. To give you an example:

The pattern is **abca**, so the first and the last letter are the same. For my application, an equivalent way to write this would be **1 2 3 1**, where the digits are just variables. The data I have is **thistextisatest**. The resulting algorithm should give me two correct matches here, **text** and **test**. Because only in these two cases, the first and the fourth letter are the same, as in the pattern.

As a second example, the pattern **abcd** should return 12 matches (one for each position in thistextisat). Since no variable in the pattern is repeated, it is trivially matched everywhere. Even in the case of **text** and **test**, because it is legal that the variables **a** and **d** of the pattern map to the same symbol.

The goal of this algorithm should be to detect similarities in written language. Imagine having a dictionary of the English language and parsing it with the pattern **unseen** or equivalently **1 2 3 4 4 2**. You would then see that, for example, the word **belittle** contains the same pattern of letters.

So, now that I hopefully made clear what I need, I have some questions:

- What is this algorithm called? Is it a well-known problem that has been solved?
- Are there publications on the matter? It is really hard to find anything useful when you don't know the correct search terms to separate this problem from regular pattern matching.
- Is there a ready implementation of this?

I have not used Regex for anything too complicated, so I don't know if anything like this would even be possible in Regex, when you basically do not care about the symbols as such, but only consider the pattern of their occurences.

I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: It is interesting. However, you can match all that with regexes. First, `(.).{2}\1` (or `((.).{2}\2)` to capture text better) will return "test" and "text" (https://regex101.com/r/cV7bD1/3), and second, `(?=(.{4}))` will return 12 matches you are interested in (https://regex101.com/r/cV7bD1/2). So, the main point could be translating the pattern to numbers, checking for repetitive numbers, and creating a corresponding regex.

Comment: I understand your suggestion, but this rather seems like the last-resort approach to me, if I have to generate a regex from each pattern (of which there will be millions). It would, of course, be more convenient to have some kind of wild card regex (or a completely separate algorithm) which can handle all instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need regular expressions here. Your search term:

```
unseen
123442
```

This has six characters, so index each word of your text into 6-mers

belittle

```
12,12,12,12,11,12,12 2-mers
123,123,123,122,112,123 3-mers
1234,1234,1233,1223,1123 4-mers
12345,12344,12334,12234 5-mers
123455,123442,123321 6-mers
```

So just looking at the 6-mers, you've got a match. Any 6 digit number less than your search term would also be a match, to allow for the abcd (1234) case matching an abca (1231) word.

So given a search term of n characters, just split each word into its constituent n-mers and check for numeric equal or less than.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! What you pointed out with your example is that no matter how many letters the data has, if you split it into n-mers, you will always find the pattern (with the same numbering of the variables). I now see that this also allows sub-pattern matching quite trivially, because you can build the n-mers of the pattern as well.